# Where can I find and how to modify generated html form elements in rails7

Tags: web-component, ruby-on-rails-7, carbon-design-system

i have this code in rails
`<%= button_to "Destroy this post", @post, method: :delete %>`
and it is returning `<button .... /button>` but I want to return `<bx-btn .... /bx-btn>` instead. How can I achieve that and where exactly I can modify the code? Thank you!

I tried to search but nothing results in sufficient explanatory to mi issue or I could not comprehend the answer. I tried rails guides but I cant seem to find the documentation or I cant decribe what I am searching for.

Comment: BTW, `button_to` returns a input of type submit, not a button tag. For that, you must call the `button_tag` helper.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to monkey-patch `button_to`, probably isn't a good idea.
A better choice might be to create a helper that works as a [`content_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag) extension, like:

```rb
def bx_button(content_or_options_with_block = nil, options = nil, escape = true, &block)
  content_tag('bx-btn', content_or_options_with_block, options, escape) do
    block.call if block_given?
  end
end
```

then use it as:

```
<%= bx_button "Destroy this post", method: :delete %>
```

or as a block:

```
<%= bx_button method: :delete do %>
  Destroy this post
  <any-other-tag-you-need-inside-bx-btn/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: does not work, how can I monkey patch? I want the very same functionality as button or button to, eventually in textarea and other elements, but instead of button I want to use bx-btn and other web components... `undefined method `each_pair' for #<Post _id: 63810ac5f59e5356ad39a08f, created_at: 2022-11-25 18:34:45.524 UTC, updated_at: 2022-11-25 18:34:45.524 UTC, title: "Hello", content: "Content"`

Comment: what should I search for in documentation? I cant find any piece of code where is stated the generated html of `button_to`

Comment: I don't get it, you got `undefined method each_pair'` with the code I shared you?, but I didn't add any post instance, it doesn't make sense

Comment: About monkeypatching `button_to`, I repeat isn't a good idea, but if you inisist, take a look [the rails docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.2.8/ActionView%2FHelpers%2FUrlHelper:button_to) at the end appears the "view source" link where you could see how that html is generated.

Comment: Thank you, I find that maybe https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder could solve my problem.